# why can service worker respondWith() return a fetch object instead of a real response?

Tags: fetch, service-worker

I was reading the MDN docs, and got confused why `event.respondWith` can have a `fetch` object returned? Isn't the actual request initiator expecting a response instead of a fetch?

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Prevent the default, and handle the request ourselves.
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    // Try to get the response from a cache.
    const cachedResponse = await caches.match(event.request);
    // Return it if we found one.
    if (cachedResponse) return cachedResponse;
    // If we didn't find a match in the cache, use the network.
    return fetch(event.request);
  }());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual request initiator is not expecting a response. It is expecting a promise that resolves into a response. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/respondWith) say exactly that:

> The respondWith() method of FetchEvent prevents the browser's default
>   fetch handling, and allows you to provide a promise for a Response
>   yourself.

You are not returning a fetch object here when you call `fetch(event.request)`. You are calling the fetch method which returns a promise that resolves into a response.
You can return any promise that resolves to a response here, like so:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
  resolve(/* { Fake Response Object } */);
  }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: but if return a fetch, there will be two request saw in the dev tool, why? should it be only one?